# Is there anyway to improve the Javascript Built Apps's web page loading time?

Tags: codenameone

I found the first web page loading time for CN1 Javascript Built taking too long, need about 2 minutes.

I attached the Chrome's network loading screen shot, found the classes.js is the most heavy page, possible to zip it?

Second, there is 2 theme files that downloaded sequentially, is it possible for them to load at the same time?

[image]

Kindly advice.

Comment: I have opened an issue related to this.  You can track it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would answer that you can look at the [performance section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html) but the relevant sections there relate to reducing the `theme.res` size which seems pretty small in your case.

The largest portion in your code is the class files so I'm guessing that the best way to reduce them is to further reduce dependencies so the obfucator can remove more dead code. Keep in mind that the classes.js file is cached and can be deployed via CDN's such as cloudflair to improve download speeds. It can be served in a gzipped form as well which is a part of the CDN repertoire.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, I can use the CDN to improve the loading time.

I found that while the page loading the theme files, it just showing a blank page, and the browser seems like stop loading (no any loading animation). This make user confuse thought this was loading error, and keep reloading/refresh the page.. Possible still keep showing the loading page while loading theme files?

Comment: I agree this is something we need to improve, the loading code should ideally show until the first form is shown.